# Redshift Formulas

Tags: redshift

I was wondering where does the formula for redshift $$z=\frac vc$$ come from? Can it be derived from the definition of redshift $$z={\lambda_{observed} - \lambda_{emitted}\over \lambda_{emitted}}?$$

Comment: Cool! I've just asked [How to best format the question mark that immediately follows an equation in a question sentence?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31283/284619)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-relativistic formula can be derived analogously to the derivation of the [Doppler effect for sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect). Namely, draw waves as consecutive parallel lines moving at velocity $c$ whose distance is $\lambda$ (if the source is not moving) and let the source move away at $v$. You will find that the distance has increased and became the observed wavelength, which is $\lambda$ - $vt$ = $\lambda + v\lambda/c$ = $\lambda(1+\frac{v}{c})$.

Note that this formula is not relativistic and that there is cosmological (as pointed out by @Alchimista in the comment below) as well as gravitational redshift, so the formula above only describes only one of the effects that cause redshift or blueshift.

Comment: To OP. Beware that in cosmology there is a third kind of "Doppler“ shift. That one due to expansion. My comment might be unrelated or unrccessary, though.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [Is there still a red shift when moving perpendicular to the direction of incidence?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35382/7982) It isn't necessarily relevant here but I'm just mentioning it for completeness.